# Zend_Paginator creating issues in webpage

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I am using Zend_Paginator in my web-page, where I get the same records in each page....

For Eg. I got the same 4 records in different pages...?

```
$page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($userDetails);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(4);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

$this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

What may be the problem?

Please help.....

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this records you get fro DB, you should make `limitPage($page, $rowCount)`. Or if your data not from DB, you should filtering it by other way. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say with that little information but the most obvious explanation is that `$page` does not contain what you think it does. In other words, make sure you are actually sending a page parameter in the Request and make sure `$page` contains that page number.

If you can confirm that the correct page number is passed to `setCurrentPageNumber`, use a Debugger to step through the program flow to see what happens. Consider upgrading your question with more details then.